# A Server in the SharePoint 2013 farm is not responding.

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

From my central admin, manage servers, i could able to see my server but
Config cache is not getting updated even though the timer server and SharePoint admin server is started.

When i checked the eventviewer logs, i found below 2 errors.

```
Database 'SharePoint_Config' on SQL Server instance 'SPSQLServer' is not empty and does not match current database schema

SharePoint object [SPConfigurationDatabase] is in an unsupported state, and could not be used by the current farm.
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ULS logs, i got this..

`07/29/2018 17:32:55.29 hostcontrollerservice (0x0484) 0x0B74 
SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPConfigurationDatabaseSequence ajyxu 
ERROR Upgrade object too new (build version = 15.0.4981.1002, schema version = 15.0.12.0). 
Current server (build version = 15.0.4841.1000, schema version = 15.0.11.0). 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

the FARM build version is different to farm build version for some reason, installed the last installed CU on FARM and ran PSConfig and everything came backup again.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue in one of our production server and running the psconfig fixed it. this command i ran at that time.

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force
```

Comment: I logged in with my FARM account, and run "Get-SPFARM" command, i get an error "Local Farm cannot be accessible. I could able to do the same from other server in the FARM with same account. Should i try re-installing SharePoint Server on that server?

Comment: what error you see when you run get-spfarm command on the bad server? its look some permission issue or blockage. could you please check the uls logs and event log for more clue

Comment: I this error when i run get-spfarm
Get-SPFarm : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is
properly configured, currently available, and that you have the appropriate
permissions to access the database before trying again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-SPFarm
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SpCmdletGetFarm:
   SpCmdletGetFarm) [Get-SPFarm], SPCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SpCmdletGetFarm

Comment: I dont see any other errors apart from the above mentioned errors from event viewer

Comment: are you runinng the command with farm admin account or the same account which is working on other servers?

Comment: yes, i ran it with my farm account

Comment: either account running the command having issue, check if SharePoint Timer service is running on the server? also check if the their is connection issues. clear config cache on the server. is it the server which you recovered from vm snapshot?

Comment: yes, it is the same server which i recovered from VMSnaps. Timer server is working fine, I see all the services are up apart from distributed cache, When restoring the VMSnaps, i exactly did the same way as this post says. ( https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mossbiz/2013/02/22/sharepoint-vs-snapshots-part-2/)

Comment: i think, time to rebuild the server.

Comment: lol!! that would be my first rebuilding effort, any things to be remembered, best practices to rebuild a server?